# Error Executing OpenSSL Commands in Windows for Google Pay Integration: Path Not Found

Tags: windows, bash, cmd, openssl, google-pay

I'm working on integrating Google Pay and need to generate a public key from a PEM file using OpenSSL commands. My environment is Windows 10, and I'm encountering issues adapting commands typically used in a Unix/Linux environment.

Here's the command I tried:

```
cmd
C:\Users\rodri>openssl ec -in key.pem -pubout -text -noout 2> /dev/null | grep "pub:" -A5 | sed 1d | xxd -r -p | base64 | paste -sd "\0" -
```

I attempted to modify it for Windows, but received various errors, including

> "The system cannot find the path specified"

and

> "'xxd' is not recognized as an internal or external command".

Could someone guide how to correctly execute these steps in Windows? Or suggest an alternative approach to generate the public key in the required format for Google Pay integration?

Thank you for any assistance you can offer!

Comment: try to run this command where you have kept your key.pem file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seemingly, you are trying to run a Linux based series of commands in a Windows based terminal.

You'll need to either run this inside WSL, or adjust the command to do the same exact output, but without using Linux based paths like `/dev/null` or commands like `grep` or `sed`.

Comment: Hello @ReanimatedManX   I downloaded WSL, I run this command on it `caroc@PC:~$ openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -outform DER -in key.pem -nocrypt | base64 | paste -sd "\0" -` but throws the error:
`Can't open "key.pem" for reading, No such file or directory`, 
I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-19041-Microsoft x86_64) How can I solve this issue?

Comment: The `-in` argument expects you to create `key.pem` file prior to running the command.

Comment: Something like this? `openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -outform DER -"C:\Users\rodri\Desktop\key" key.pem -nocrypt | b
ase64 | paste -sd "\0" -`  or `openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -outform DER - in "C:\Users\rodri\Desktop\key" key.pem -nocrypt | b
ase64 | paste -sd "\0" -` ?